# i can't give more sound in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

i am facing sound problem in ubuntu 12.04. I switched completely to Ubuntu 12.04 everything is fine instead when I play any track or video, the visual performance is good but the sounds flickers always and when I try to increase the volume it starts to flicker more. I checked my hardware, hardware drivers etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off time based scheduling in the sound system.

Open your Terminal and execute these commands:

> sudo echo "load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0" >> /etc/pulse/default.pa
>
> pulseaudio -k
>
> pulseaudio --start

Answer (score 0):

Use following commands to control volume:

To get the index number of sinks:

```
pactl list short sinks | awk '{print $1}'
```

Control volume:

```
 pactl set-sink-volume <index number> <volume in %>
```

e.g: `pactl set-sink-volume 0 100%`